# Getting employees in each dept using LINQ LAMBDA

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to join two tables employee and department using LINQ and trying to get results in given below image format. Can some one help how to achieve this.

[image]

how to achieve employees present in each department.

Here is my code

```
var EmpList = (from d in Department
 join e in Employee on d.ID equals e.ID
 select new
 {
   ID = d.ID, Name = d.Name, Location = d.location,  Employess =  
   e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Gender
 });
```

The above code not fully written. I am not getting any ideas how to achieve this.

```
var elist = from d in db.Departments
                    join e in db.Employees on d.ID equals e.ID
                    group d by e.DepartmentId into g
                    select new { Details = g };
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Change your join's on condition to d.ID equals e.DepartmentID and write groupby d.Name

Comment: Perhaps this article will help?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a structure like this:

```
var depts = new[] {
    new Dept { ID = 1, Name = "IT", Location = "New York" },
    new Dept { ID = 2, Name = "HR", Location = "London" },
    new Dept { ID = 3, Name = "Payroll", Location = "Sydney" }
};

var employees = new[] {
    new Employee { ID = 1, FirstName = "Mark", DeptID = 1 },
    new Employee { ID = 2, FirstName = "Steve", DeptID = 3 },
    new Employee { ID = 3, FirstName = "Ben", DeptID = 1 },
    new Employee { ID = 4, FirstName = "Philip", DeptID = 2 },
    new Employee { ID = 5, FirstName = "Mary", DeptID = 2 },
    new Employee { ID = 6, FirstName = "Valarie", DeptID = 3 },
    new Employee { ID = 7, FirstName = "John", DeptID = 1 }
};
```

You can use LINQ Join and GroupBy to get the desired data:

```
var result = depts
    .Join(employees.GroupBy(x => x.DeptID), dept => dept.ID, empGroup => empGroup.Key,
        (dept, empGroup) => new { 
            Name = dept.Name, 
            Location = dept.Location, 
            Employees = empGroup.ToArray() 
        });
```

Or the same in SQL-like syntax:

```
var result = from dept in depts
             join empGroup in (
                from e in employees
                group e by e.DeptID into g
                select g
             ) on dept.ID equals empGroup.Key
             select new { 
                Name = dept.Name, 
                Location = dept.Location, 
                Employees = empGroup.ToArray()
             };
```

What does this actually do?

1. Employees are grouped by `DeptID`.
2. Departments are joined with this grouping and result into a collection of anonymous objects of desired format. Of course, you can use a strongly-typed class.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing the `GroupJoin` :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Wow, yeah :D Thank you, I did never hear about this method before.

Comment: Ivanstoev your solution is working great ..I tried in different way but its not working can let me know what i did wrong. Just want to know my mistake    ..i copied my code in question

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Meta
{
}
```

public  partial class Empolyees

```
{
    public string depart
    {
        get
        {
            EmpolyeeEntities db = new EmpolyeeEntities();

            var empid = db.Empolyees.Select(e=>e.Department).SingleOrDefault();

             var dpname = db.Department1.Where(x => x.Id == empid).Select(f => f.Department).SingleOrDefault();


            return dpname.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: empid get the ids of employee table ,by using it bring rows of department table using where then using select() get the valu of department